# How can i delete a video from my vimeo account using vimeo API

Tags: vimeo

I have impelemted a single user application. So I'm hard coding the access token in my code itself. I'm able to upload video to my vimeo account.
Now, I would like to be able to delete a specific video from my account using VideoId.

How can we achieve this ?
does vimeo support deleting a video ?

I know that we can do it using the old API (v2) https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.delete

But how can we achieve the same with the new API ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#DELETE/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D

Comment: umm ah, couldn't find this endpoint in the api docs. Thank you CBroe

Answer (score 0):

The description for how to delete a video with their current API is here:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#DELETE/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D